# Bloomberg-R Depth of market access

Tags: mdm, bloomberg

I have have successfully retrieved book depth pricing using the `BEST_BIDn` BDP field where n is 1 through 9 and represents the market-making position.

What field will give the corresponding bid size?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `BEST_BIDn_SZ` so for example: `BEST_BID1_SZ`.